# Is there any special requirements for deploying Universal App ( Windows 10 ) with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When I create a new Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1) I can build, deploy and run on the simulator (as one would expect ).

When I try create a new Blank App using Windows Universal (which I assume relates to Windows 10), I can build but fail deploying on the Windows 10 virtual machines that comes with Windows Kit 10.

Not much info, Visual Studio 2015 only reports that it cannot deploy.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
1>  App2 -> c:\users\testuser\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App2\App2\bin\x86\Debug\App2.exe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: App2, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
`
```

I also have a real windows phone but since it runs a slightly older version than what I can set as target I guess I am not to surprised it won't deploy on it.

Comment: What do you mean by Windows 10 virtual machines that comes with Windows Kit 10? Do you mean the simulator, or mobile emulators? Are you running on Windows 10 (and if yes, can you deploy to local machine)?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have enabled the developer mode on both desktop and mobile device